# Silencing JSLint warnings in brackets

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, jslint, adobe-brackets

I just started a gulp-angular Yeoman project and opened it in brackets, and nearly everywhere I'm getting `'something' was used before it was defined`, specifically `'angular' was used before it was defined`. I've messed around with extensions and other fixes, but I honestly don't know what I'm doing and I haven't been able to find any good documentation.

What can I do to silence these warnings across the entire project? In other words, how can I avoid using `/*global angular*/` in pretty much every file in my project?

Here's a quick example of one of my controller declarations:

```
/*global console*/

(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('sbk')
        .controller('MainController', MainController);

    /** @ngInject */
    function MainController() {
        console.log('Woo!');
    }
})();
```

Which results in the following JSLint warnings:

```
'angular' was used before it was defined.
'MainController' was used before it was defined.
'MainController' was used before it was defined.
Move the invocation into the parens that contain the function.
```

Edit: updated to make my issue a little clearer

Answer (score 1):

http://jshint.com/docs/options/#globals

Provide a list of globals, and you're done.

It's not clear if you're using jshint or jslint; your tags say one, your text another.

Comment: Ugh, I'm a stackexchange noob, sorry for the crappy formatting. Just posted by .jshintrc file above. So should my jshint config silence jslint errors?

Comment: @Spencer I think jshintrc files are for, unsurprisingly, jshint. jshint != jslint.

Comment: Well yea, but I tagged the problem as jslint and included jslint errors and you sent me to a jshint site so I got confused. I'm new to jslint/hint so this problem is throwing me for a loop.

Comment: @Spencer You said you were editing a jshintrc file in your post--why edit a jshint file if you're using jslint? Hopefully you can understand why it was confusing.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. So yea, the problem is with JSLint errors. Any ideas what I can do to silence them?

Comment: @Spencer I don't think JSLint works like that. It's one of the reasons JSHint exists, in fact, although there are others. IMO JSLint has been popularly deprecated in favor of JSHint or JSCS.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so remember that JSLint is just a JavaScript file, and most JSLint plugins I've used has the source shoved in the install somewhere (though the Visual Studio plugin embeds it into a dll!), so you can *always* get it to do what you want [within reason].

In your case, the absolute worst case is that you initialize the list of predefined variables with the namespaces you want JSLint to assume are *always* considered to be in scope. I'm going to show you how to set that globally within Brackets, which might not always be the best thing to do, and you need to keep in mind if you're linting another project that *doesn't* have Angular, well, you've screwed up JSLint.

(Honestly, I'm disappointed that Brackets doesn't have `global` as a global in its preferences.json file. Guess I should submit a patch.)

There are lots of ways we could do this. I'm going to add a namespace to the `standard` object. You could also limit its exposure by adding to the `browser` collection of globals (line 497 in my Bracket install's jslint file). We could also create a new JSLint directive option, similar to `browser`. That's not quick 'n' dirty, but is probably The Right Way to do this without submitting a Brackets patch. But for now, let's just do the quick 'n' dirty fix.

I'm using Windows. If you're not, YMWV. I do not use Brackets daily, so I haven't tested this in a production coding environment. If anything doesn't work, I'd be interested to hear it, however, and I'll see if I can find what's wrong.

---

#### TL;DR. Just the code, ma'am.

The jslint.js file you want is here, if you went with the default install location:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\www\extensions\default\JSLint\thirdparty\jslint`

(Just for fun, notice that the version of JSLint we're using is from 2011!!?! Come on, Brackets guys!)

`standard` is, in my file, on line 974. Here's what it had originally:

```
// standard contains the global names that are provided by the
// ECMAScript standard.

    standard = array_to_object([
        'Array', 'Boolean', 'Date', 'decodeURI', 'decodeURIComponent',
        'encodeURI', 'encodeURIComponent', 'Error', 'eval', 'EvalError',
        'Function', 'isFinite', 'isNaN', 'JSON', 'Math', 'Number', 'Object',
        'parseInt', 'parseFloat', 'RangeError', 'ReferenceError', 'RegExp',
        'String', 'SyntaxError', 'TypeError', 'URIError'
    ], false),
```

Here's a test JavaScript snippet I want to lint that uses my global object, `util`:

```
/*jslint sloppy:true, white:true */
utils.spam();
utils.spammySpam();

smutils.spam();
```

All we need to do is to add `, 'utils'` to `standard`, and we're done.

```
    standard = array_to_object([
        'Array', 'Boolean', 'Date', 'decodeURI', 'decodeURIComponent',
        'encodeURI', 'encodeURIComponent', 'Error', 'eval', 'EvalError',
        'Function', 'isFinite', 'isNaN', 'JSON', 'Math', 'Number', 'Object',
        'parseInt', 'parseFloat', 'RangeError', 'ReferenceError', 'RegExp',
        'String', 'SyntaxError', 'TypeError', 'URIError', 'utils'
    ], false),
```

To be overly clear, you'd add `'angular'` and `'MainController'` to your `standard` object in place of `'utils'`.

Btw, Crockford (JSLint's creator and maintainer) would hate that we did that. I don't *really* blame him.

Now I get an error for `smutils`, but not `utils`. Luckily, the global directive still works with this setup:

```
/*jslint sloppy:true, white:true */
/*global smutils */
utils.spam();
utils.spammySpam();

smutils.spam();
```

And we're JSLint friendly again.

Hacking JSLint directly might not have most favored option status, but it works.

Btw, re: Dave's comment, "IMO JSLint has been popularly deprecated in favor of JSHint or JSCS," I'm not so sure. Just as an example, which does Brackets use out of the box? The best part about JSLint is how much *less* subjective discussion has to happen to get a large team on the same page. And trust me, Crockford's not going to tell you to do something that's indefensibly *wrong*.

He might hurt your feelings, and he might ask you to do something that hurts at first, but I really think JSLint can teach a team a *lot* about JavaScript best practices. It's worth living in JSLint for a while before jumping to JSHint.