# JSLint - How To Ignore Node Environment HashBang?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jslint

Is there a way to ignore the Node HashBang in JSLint (Running via Brackets)?

`#! /usr/bin/env node`

Produces the error: 'Unexpected !' and then stops checking the rest of the file. The line seems to be needed for my NPM module to work properly in Windows.

Thanks

Comment: That line is completely ignored on Windows.

Comment: @SLaks Clearly not as I tried running the npm module on a number of Windows computers and it failed with JS runtime errors without that line present.

Comment: What error did you get? How are you running it?

Comment: It says required [object] on a certain line of the code without that line present at the top of the file. Running it as ```macget command```

Comment: @SLaks Fwiw, it blows up at JSLint.com, which is fairly canonical. ;^) And it blows up even if you have the Node.js directive set to `true`, though the error is "Unexpected character '#'." On Windows Brackets, I get `Expected an identifier and instead saw '#'.` Is there another platform (other than SLaks' Brackets) for JSLint where the hashbang *is* ignored? Wonder what SLaks did to suppress it.

Comment: Fwiw, see [yesterday's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32061758/1028230) where I suggest hacking Bracket's jslint.js file. That's almost always the worst case.